# To remove id that contains '\' in DataWeave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

**Input**

```
{
    "phone": [
        {
            "id": "r/2",
            "time": "2020-01-01"
        },
        {
            "id": "31",
            "time": "2020-02-21"
        },
        {
            "id": "244",
            "time": "2020-01-16"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Desired Output:** to filter by date range, then remove id that contains '/'

```
[244]
```

**Attempted:** I managed to filter the date but not remove the id that contains '/'

```
(payload.phone filter ($.time >= "2020-01-01" and $.time <= "2020-01-21")).id distinctBy $
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used functions for easier reuse:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun filterDateRanges(a, dateStart, dateEnd) = a filter ($.time >= dateStart and $.time <= dateEnd)
fun filterIdChar(a, c)=a filter !($.id contains c)
---
filterDateRanges(filterIdChar(payload.phone, "/"), "2020-01-01", "2020-01-21").id distinctBy $
```

Comment: Hi, can i check with you how to replace instead? like if first character is "/" then change "/" to "?" and change "2" to "1" ?

Comment: That's a different question. Instead of filter use map.